# Packing program with PyInstaller breaks it

Tags: python, process, exec, pyinstaller, executable

```
import pyautogui
import time
from threading import Thread
import os
import signal
from multiprocessing import Process
import keyboard


def clicker():
    while True:
        pyautogui.mouseDown(button="left")
        time.sleep(0.05)
        pyautogui.mouseUp(button="left")
        time.sleep(3)


def exit_thrd():
    global running
    keyboard.wait("m")
    string_ext = (f"if running:"
                  f"\n  proces_{broj_procesa}.kill()"
                  f"\n  proces_{broj_procesa}.join()"
                  f"\n  proces_{broj_procesa}.close()"
                  )
    exec(string_ext)

    print("Exited!")
    os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGTERM)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ext_thrd = Thread(target=exit_thrd)
    ext_thrd.start()

    broj_procesa = 0

    # instructions
    print("Started!\nPress n to start-stop\nPress m to exit")

    running = False
    while True:
        keyboard.wait("n")
        if not running:
            running = True
            broj_procesa += 1
            exec(f"proces_{broj_procesa} = Process(target=clicker)\nproces_{broj_procesa}.start()")
        else:
            running = False
            exec(f"proces_{broj_procesa}.kill()\nproces_{broj_procesa}.join()")
```

I made a simple auto clicker for Minecraft. When I start it, it waits for me to press n to start clicking. If I press n again it stops, and then I can press n to start again. When I press m it exits. It is working just fine when I run it from PyCharm, but when I pack it to executable with PyInstaller, it breaks. Arguments I used for creating EXE with PyInstaller are:

```
pyinstaller "auto-click.py" --console --icon "click-bot.ico" --uac-admin --onefile --name "Click-Bot"
```

Now when I run EXE created by PyInstaller, it prints out instructions message, but when I click n, it prints it out again. And again and again for every time I press n. When I press m it exits without problem tough. I know I probably didn't make this program the best way possible because I know usage of exec is not really desirable, but I needed to get around starting process again, because when I start and stop process, and try to start it again, it pops error, so this way I'm just making new processes. Feel free to correct my program, and also some of the variable names are in Croatian but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: instead of using `exec()` to create variables `process_1`, `process_2` you could normally keep processes on list - `process = []` and later `p = Process()`, `p.start()`, `process.append(p)`. And `process[broj_proc-1].kill()`, `process[broj_proc-1].join()`. In all languages you have `list` or `array` specially to keep many elements.

Comment: if you get error then show it in question. always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.